# How to convert a ByteArray to a ShortArray in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

If I have a well-formed `ByteArray` (say, `byteArrayOf(12, 0, 24, 0)`), what is the easiest way to convert this into a `ShortArray`?

For simplicity's sake, assume little-endian unless endianness handling is easy too.

Resultant `ShortArray` should look like `(12, 24)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain why, but it appears that Kotlin treats bytes as if they are signed and the above answer work only when the first byte of each pair is < 127.

For example (editing the above to return correct answers):

```
    val byteArray = byteArrayOf(211.toByte(), 0, 24, 0)
    val shortArray = ShortArray(byteArray.size / 2) {
        (byteArray[it * 2].toUByte().toInt() + (byteArray[(it * 2) + 1].toInt() shl 8)).toShort()
    }
    println(shortArray.toList()) // [211, 24]
```

Using the above code with the same values returns incorrect information as [-45, 24]

Comment: I believe this is because bytes are signed in Java, and kotlin compiles to the same bytecode, and runs on the same virtual machine implementations. I've read the reason for signed bytes in Java is because one of the language designers found them simpler. Thank you for your contribution here.

Answer (score 6):

You can process the `ByteArray` as a list with [`.chunked()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html), though you have to manually convert the two bytes into a `Short`:

```
val bytes = byteArrayOf(12, 0, 24, 0)
val shorts = bytes
    .asList()
    .chunked(2)
    .map { (l, h) -> (l.toInt() + h.shl(8)).toShort() }
    .toShortArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

Without transforming to list as @hotkey answer :

```
val byteArray = byteArrayOf(12, 0, 24, 0)
val shortArray = ShortArray(byteArray.size / 2) {
    (byteArray[it * 2] + (byteArray[(it * 2) + 1].toInt() shl 8)).toShort()
}
println(shortArray.toList()) // [12, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ByteBuffer`

```kotlin
val bytes = byteArrayOf(12, 0, 24, 0)
val shorts = ShortArray(bytes.size / 2)
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer()[shorts]
```